# Firebase - Check if logged in user id equals realtime database value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

currently I'm working on a new Firebase web project.
I want to check if the current logged in user ID is saved in the realtime database to give the user some specific possibilities / rights on my site.

**Realtime Database:**

```
users
>*User ID* (the value to compare)
```

My question: Which JavaScript code can compare the currently logged in Firebase user with this db value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure by now you have found that all your questions have been answered on the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

On your web app, the currently signed in user can be gotten using

```
firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

To compare the logged in user with child key do this

```
var user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref('users/'+user_id).once('value').then(userSnapshot => {
    if(userSnapshot.exists()){
        //allow user perform action

    }else{
       // do not allow
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```